# BIOS Write-Protect Screw HP Chromebook 14

Tags: chromebook

Anybody who knows what the BIOS Write-Protect Screw is on this image? This is the board of a HP Chromebook 14 (K6C85EA). The other images that I can find are different :-(

Need to know because I want to install chrubuntu

[image]

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HP_Chromebook_14#Locating_the_Write-Protect_Screw

Comment: The disassembly pictures look different :-(

Comment: I'm also unable to find the 'hints' on this board

Comment: What is that large silvery metal chassis covering the green circuit board? Can that be removed? Perhaps  it's under there?

Comment: I don't think chrubuntu requires modifying uefi/bios: http://chromeos-cr48.blogspot.com ...can't find anything about it... though this is a requirement for full native linux. Here are 2 links to custom firmware for this purpose: [mrchromebox](https://mrchromebox.tech) or [johnlewis.ie](https://johnlewis.ie/custom-chromebook-firmware/rom-download/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ymx2R.jpg) is the location of the write protect screw for HP Chromebook 14 (nvidia nyan blaze).

During the process of removing this write protection, the battery will be disconnected. As a consequence the boot loader will lost any configuration change made with crossystem (dev_boot_usb, dev_boot_legacy or dev_boot_signed_only).

If chromeos (as shipped by Google) is still installed on your chromebook this is not an issue. On the other hand, if you have erased the content of the eMMC, you won't be able to boot from USB or the legacy partition.

Make sure you have:

1. Backup everything first
2. Generate a usb recovery key

Once the screw removed, you can verify if it succeeded with:

```
    localhost ~ # flashrom -p internal:bus=spi --wp-status
    WP: status: 0x00b8
    WP: status.srp0: 1
    WP: status.srp1: 0
    WP: write protect is enabled.
    WP: write protect range: start=0x00000000, len=0x00200000
    localhost ~ # flashrom -p internal:bus=spi --wp-disable
    SUCCESS
    localhost ~ # flashrom -p internal:bus=spi --wp-status
    WP: status: 0x0038
    WP: status.srp0: 0
    WP: status.srp1: 0
    WP: write protect is disabled.
    WP: write protect range: start=0x00000000, len=0x00200000
```

Comment: really useful. I'm trying to finish up a linux install on a HP CB 11 and trying to get rid of the developer mode warning screen. This helps get some perspective as I try a few different things ... thanks!

Answer (score 3):

On the FALCO Chromebook 14,

- there is a LARGE WHITE ARROW > icon next to the BIOS write protect screw on the green circuit board. ALSO,
- from a glance the screw doesn't look to be a supporting screw.
- it can be recognized by the fact that the copper circle it sits on is split in half "( )" vs "O". The screw connects the two halves, making the bios unwriteable.

[image]

Those are indicators I would use when looking at your Chromebook. However, from the picture, I do not see a screw that matches that description.

Comment: thanks for your comment, I just removed the screw and it looks just like you described. see: https://i.imgur.com/o3uwheQ.jpeg

Comment: The other ones all look like the top screw, which I've shown in the attached image. So the WP screw must be the one on the bottom right corner of the motherboard. https://i.imgur.com/xeUAZrG.jpeg