# how to flash a user friendly bios to a chromebook hp 14

Tags: bios, chromebook

this article was just great

[BIOS Write-Protect Screw HP Chromebook 14](https://superuser.com/questions/837870/bios-write-protect-screw-hp-chromebook-14)

esp jonathan's answer.  amazing

as far as that article goes, i couldn't / didn't make a recovery 'key' for the bios

chromebook is:

Product   F0H09UA

hp        14-q063cl

i had to take out the ssd because it was totally fried as the unit had not been cleaned, and the exhaust vent was covered by lint.  so i'm starting with a clean ssd

so i have never been so angry with hardware developers and google for restricting access to my usb port.  these security features are so prohibitive that i would rather get ransomware or a virus

how do i flash the bios with something that isn't going to hinder my progress ?  i want to be able to see the bios / boot menu option at startup

i don't want a chromebook.  but instead of shipping it to a recycling center i would rather reprogram it, and i want to start with the bios

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you don't want a Chromebook buy something else. Now, if you want an OS other than ChromeOS - different than the hardware itself - that may be possible but not officially supported in all instances.

Answer (score 0):

The HP Chromebook 14" has the ARM Cortex A15 CPU.
As such, you can't install neither Windows nor Linux.

Installing another BIOS won't help you do anything else with this
Chromebook than using ChromeOS, so there is really no point in it
(and might not be possible)

For some definitive sources, see :

- [MrChromebox.tech](https://mrchromebox.tech/#home)
- [Getting Started for installing Windows](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrultrabook/comments/aufp1q/getting_started_read_this_first)

Comment: The initial assertion is factually wrong. 1. There are many Linux distros that can be installed in ARM hardware and specifically in Chromebooks. Ubuntu can even be installed without messing with  the BIOS or removing ChromeOS. 2. Installing Windows is also possible albeit not officially supported (the same for desktop Linux) -> https://www.lifewire.com/install-windows-on-chromebook-4778088 Again, not helpful and completely wrong.

Comment: Correction (about Ubuntu): https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-on-chromebook#1-overview This is officially supported after all.

Comment: MrChromebox.tech is even cited in your first link, which says that only Intel x86 is supported. I believe it as an acknowledged source. If you think otherwise, then please put up your answer and let the poster decide.

Comment: I have no answer for this, the question being about a "user-friendly BIOS" (whatever that is) and reads like a rant, not an actual question and very poorly researched. My comment is a correction to your comment-as-an-answer. Windows CAN run on ARM hardware (and it's nothing new): https://www.windowscentral.com/windows-10-arm-microsofts-key-chromebook-market but, of course, this is a lot more complicated than using Ubuntu and with no discernible advantage, an ARM compatible OS doesn't mean it can run all the software you want because that software must support the architecture as well.

Comment: "reads like a rant, not an actual question and very poorly researched"
like, uh, i don't need to research the fact that i can't boot to a usb drive.  my ssd is fried and i ordered a replacement.  i'll spare you the details and specifications of the m.2 slot.  i don't want to reinstall chrome os.  as ChanganAuto suggested, i would like to install ubuntu.  is it possible to just install ubuntu without reinstalling chromeos, (even though chromeos is a linux distribution).  i also read mrchromebox's walkthrough.  i understand that he is flashing the bios from within chromeos

Comment: (comment)  this is my first experience with chromebook.  i was doing my best to avoid them, but i couldn't